# Regex on ;) smilie

Tags: regex

A minor inconvenience my users have found is that if they use a smilie such as `>_>` at the end of parentheses (kind of like this: >_>) then during processing it is run through `htmlspecialchars()`, making it `&gt;_&gt;)` - you can see the problem, I think. The `;)` at the end is then replaced by the "Wink" smilie.

Can anyone give me a regex that will replace `;)` with the smilie, but only if the `;` is not the end of an HTML entity? (I'm sure it would involve a lookbehind but I can't seem to understand how to use them >_>)

Thank you!

Comment: No, I don't see the problem. &gt;_&gt; is the correct HTML encoded format. What replaces `;)` to a wink smile (an image I assume?). Please provide enough context for us to answer the question sensibly.

Comment: I thought I'd explained it - the ; on the HTML entity is reacting with the ) immediately after to give ;) which gets replaced.

Comment: Ah right, understood. What is creating the smilies, though? That's the code that needs to be fixed, since the html HTML is fine.

Comment: if i get the original regexp ill fix it for ya

Comment: You should perhaps consider formally decoding the HTML entities **before** searching for smileys and etc.   Something like [decode_entities](http://search.cpan.org/~gaas/HTML-Parser-3.68/lib/HTML/Entities.pm#decode_entities).  Followed of course by a [encode_entities](http://search.cpan.org/~gaas/HTML-Parser-3.68/lib/HTML/Entities.pm#encode_entities).

Comment: @Hamish: The code that creates the smileys appears to be a bunch of replacements on the text after `htmlspecialchars()` is called. That is what he is asking for help with.

Comment: @Breezer: Currently it's using `$content = str_replace(";)","{smilie image URL here}",$content)`

Comment: or first replace the smilies and then encode it

Comment: The problem with replacing the smileys first and then encoding is that normally you're replacing them with `<img>` tags, and you probably don't want those to be encoded.

Comment: @Breezer That would HTML escape the smilie HTML too. The proper way would be to parse the text in a way that does not apply replacements to replacements in the first place.

Comment: I don’t see a language tag on this smiley question. }:)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Handling smileys like `;)` is always a bit tricky - the way I would do it is transform it to the "canonical" `:wink:` *before* encoding HTML entities, and then changing only canonical-form `:{smileyname}:` smileys afterwards.

Comment: Did that, it conflicted with :) instead - but I changed the temporary form to `%wink%` instead - odds of that appearing in a regular post are fairly slim.

Comment: @Kolink: Based on what you've said, I don't think you've implemented quite what I described. What I would do is replace all `;)` with `:wink:` (and similarly, all `:)` with `:smile:`, etc.), *then* run it through `htmlspecialchars`, and only then replace `:wink:`, `:smile:`, etc. with their final versions.

Answer (score 1):

Like this:  `(?<!&[a-zA-Z0-9]+);\)`

The `(?>!...)` is a zero-width assertion that will only allow the following construct to match text that isn't preceded by the `...`.

Comment: Excellent, thank you :) Would you mind taking a moment to explain what the symbols actually mean?

Comment: Problem: `Warning: preg_replace(): Compilation failed: lookbehind assertion is not fixed length`

Comment: Yes that is a limitation of the preg_replace implementation.

Answer (score 1):

You should probably handle it along these lines, which sidesteps the issue of replacing replacements entirely:

- Break the string apart wherever a smilie occurs, convert the smilies into tokens
- HTML escape all the text nodes
- Convert all the smilie tokens into their HTML tag equivalents
- Glue everything back together

That's a bit non-trivial though. :)

Answer (score 0):

**Find:** `(&#?[a-z0-9]+;)\)`
**Replace:** `$0&#41;`

We're looking for:

```
Match the regular expression below and capture its match into backreference number 1 «(&#?[a-z0-9]+;)»
   Match the character “&” literally «&»
   Match the character “#” literally «#?»
      Between zero and one times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy) «?»
   Match a single character present in the list below «[a-z0-9]+»
      Between one and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy) «+»
      A character in the range between “a” and “z” «a-z»
      A character in the range between “0” and “9” «0-9»
   Match the character “;” literally «;»
Match the character “)” literally «\)»


Created with RegexBuddy
```

Comment: Okay, what happens if the user types `<_<)` instead? Or how about `=_=")` which I see a lot as well. Or, what if they just ended their parenthsis with an entity (such as &infin;) - A regex is the only way, short of defining replacements for every HTML entity.

Answer (score 0):

well if your intrested in a regex solution try this maybe

(?!t)([A-Za-z0-9]| );)

Answer (score 0):

If it's in php (preg_replace you said ?), you can use preg_replace_callback :

```
preg_replace_callback('#(&[a-z0-9]+)?;\)#i', 'myFunction', 'myText');
```

in the "myFunction" function, you just have to check if you got some html entity in the capturing bracket.

```
function myFunction($matches) {
    if(!empty($matches[1]) {
        return $matches[0];
    }
    return '[Smilie]';
}
```